# PostgreSQL Graphical Interface Alternatives

Tags: software-installation

Hi I am looking for some suggestions on what graphical interface we can use in PostgreSQL aside from pgAdmin3. Any recommendations?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 will have pgadmin3 1.18 and you can upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 directly to Ubuntu 14.04 when it is released in April, 2014.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Can you recommend an alternate to pgadmin3 for now?

Comment: Recommend is perhaps too strong a word to use for this. pgadmin3 is a graphical administration tool for PostgreSQL, so you can do the PostgreSQL administration from the terminal. It's not user friendly, but you only have to wait until April to get the version of pgadmin3 that you need.

Comment: Oh, I see. In this case, can you suggest maybe an alternate graphical administration tool to PostgreSQL? One that might be popular for ubuntu users? Something like Navicat for Windows maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these tools can help: http://alternativeto.net/software/pgadmin/